# How to re-grid a raster using area-overlap weighted averaging?

Tags: raster, gdal, r

I have two rasters `r and r2` with different resolutions. I want to re-sample (re-grid) `r2` to be the same as `r` using area-overlap weighted averaging:If an r grid cell is covered by more than 1 `r2`gridcell, then the value assigned is the added value of each of those `r2` cells weighed (multiplied) by the % of the r cell they cover.

There are some available methods in gdal but I think none of them matches this method. Available methods are:

```
           near, bilinear, bilinear resampling,cubic,cubic resampling,cubicspline, average ...etc
```

Has anyone done this before?